# How to simplify path integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate a function, $f(x,y)$, over the straight line path connecting $(0,k)$ to $(k,0)$ in the x-y plane, where $k>0$ (the diagonal part of the boundary of a simplex in $\Bbb{R}^2$, basically). One way of writing the integral is:

$$(1)  \qquad \qquad  \int_0^k f(x, k-x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, .$$

Suppose $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$, everything is sufficiently differentiable, and the integrals are known as well: $G(x) := \int g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$, $H(x) := \int h(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$, and accordingly:

$$ \qquad \qquad F(x,y) := \int_0^x \int_0^y f(t_1, t_2) \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \mathrm{d}t_2 \, .$$

My question is, is there any way to simplify the integral in $(1)$? Ideally I am looking for something akin to a fundamental theorem of calculus result using antiderivatives at the endpoints.

I have tried setting up the problem so we are actually walking along the path, something like:

$$ \int_0^{k\sqrt{2}} f\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}, k-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \,\mathrm{d}t $$

but I can't figure out how to proceed. Other ideas which I am not sure how to implement:

- something involving a directional derivative of $F(x,y)$?
- using the gradient of $F$ as a vector field?
- work with the integral over the whole simplex, and then take a derivative with respect to $k$?

Any tips, suggestions, ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you supposed to express $F$ in terms of $G$ and $H$? An idea would be that $$\int_0^k f(x,k-x)dx=\int_0^k g(x)h(k-x)dx$$ as you indicated, and then, since $f$ and $g$ are integrable, then, by theorem, their product $fg$ is integrable, but there is, of course, no general formula past there.

Comment: @Darrin - Ultimately, I don't care if G and H are used... mostly they are just mentioned in case directional derivates matter. So that someone could be clear in their response, e.g., $\partial F/\partial x = g(x)H(y)$. Can you think of any simplification that gets us to working with endpoints of the integral? Like, $F(k,0)$ and $F(0,k)$?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a valid way to restate the problem, but suppose we consider the integral (over the same path) of the directional derivative of $F$ in the direction, $\vec{u} = (1,1)$? Then we would have: $gH + Gh$ in place of $f$?

Comment: @Darrin - Maybe I misread the intent of your comment. Are you suggesting that I can have my endpoints, just that there is not much value in them? I.e., something like: $$\mathrm{define } \qquad P(x) := \int g(x)h(k-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ ...and then we have $P(k) - P(0)$ as the ''solution''?

Comment: I wonder if there is progress that can be made by putting restrictions on the functions? Say $f,g,h$ are all positive, so $F,G,H$ are positive and strictly increasing. Does this help anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking at a [line integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral).

Let $ z = \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}$
 be your variable, your arc can be parametrized as:
 $z(t)= 
\begin{pmatrix}
k \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
t
\begin{pmatrix}
-k \\
k \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then by definition $\int_C f(x,y) = \int_0^1 f(z(t))|z'(t)|dt=\int_0^1 f(z(t))\sqrt2dt$ and you can't say much more than that.

If you're lucky enough, and you can express $f(z(t))$ as the derivative of a function $g'(t)$, then your integral will be $g(1)-g(0)$. In the general case, you can't say much (that's why for instance, the work of a friction force in physics depends on the path, but not the work of a forces deriving from a gradient (for instance gravity)).